# `n latest` installing a version other than what it said it would

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to install the right version of node.js and npm on an Elastic Beanstalk server. Strangely,

```
   sudo n latest
```

returns this result:

```
   install : node-v7.9.0
   mkdir : /usr/local/n/versions/node/7.9.0
   fetch : https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.9.0/node-v7.9.0-linux-x64.tar.gz ######################## 100.0%
   installed : v0.10.48
```

Here, `installed` returns a version different from `install`. So when I run `node -v` it returns `v7.9.0`, but when I run `npm run prod` (the actually important step), it says `npm does not support Node.js v0.10.48` and throws a whole bunch of errors. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

The fix is in. I had to add this command to my .ebextensions config file:

```
  04_node_link:
    cwd: /tmp
    command: 'sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/7.8.0/bin/node /usr/bin/node'
```

This should link node.js to yum-installed npm correctly.